# How can I click a button while a textarea is focused with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery's focus() to alter a textarea when focused. However, I need to click a submit button outside of the focused area. The submit button currently only worked after the textarea is un-focus. Here's my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#post").focus(function(){
    $(this).css({'border-color':'green', 'height':'120px'});
  });

  $("#post").blur(function(){
    $(this).css({'border-color':'#bfbfbf', 'height':'50px'});
  });
});

function submit(){
  $('#post').val('');
}
```

```css
textarea{
  border-radius: 3px;
  resize: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="post" cols="52" id="post" placeholder="Post.." onclick="focusasd()"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="submit()"/>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ug2e5s4/2/). How can I make the submit button work even when the textarea is focused. Thanks.

Comment: concept doesn't really make sense. Can't be focused on 2 things at same time. Explain the overall expected behavior

Comment: I want a user to be able to type into the textarea and then click submit. Currently when "Submit" is clicked and the textarea is focused, the textarea simply resizes. I want the submit onclick action to work regardless if the textarea is focused.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. You can't focus on 2 elements simultaneously. If the textarea is being resized then the code that does that sounds like your problem

Comment: Just realized I could do everything with CSS. Not sure why I tried to use jquery. This is what I wanted. jsfiddle.net/0ug2e5s4/6 Thanks for you help anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/0ug2e5s4/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#post").focus(function(){
    $(this).css({'border-color':'green', 'height':'120px'});
    $('#submit').trigger('click');
  });

  $("#post").blur(function(){
    $(this).css({'border-color':'#bfbfbf', 'height':'50px'});
  });
});

function submit(){
  //Do Something
  console.log("FSDf"); 
  $('#post').val('');
}
```

```css
textarea{
  border-radius: 3px;
  resize: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="post" cols="52" id="post" placeholder="Post.."></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="submit()"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Why would focus on form control trigger a click on a submit? If user is focusing on textarea then they plan to do something inside it first

Comment: @charlietfl That's what I understood from the question and answered it. I'm just waiting for the OP to get more clarity.

Comment: When you click submit, the textarea resizes without the onclick action of the submit button being activated. I want to be able to click the submit button while the textarea is still focused and have the form be submitted eventually.

Comment: Just realized I could do everything with CSS. Not sure why I tried to use jquery. This is what I wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/0ug2e5s4/6/ Thanks for you help anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#post").focus(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'border-color': 'green',
      'height': '120px'
    });
    
    $("#submit").click(); 
    
    
  });
  
  
   $("#submit").click(function(){
        console.log("button");
    }); 

  $("#post").blur(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'border-color': '#bfbfbf',
      'height': '50px'
    });
  });
});

function submit() {
  //Do Something
  $('#post').val('');
}
```

```css
textarea {
  border-radius: 3px;
  resize: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="post" cols="52" id="post" placeholder="Post.." ></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="submit()" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If the textarea is focused when I click "Submit", the textarea just resizes without the onclick action of the submit button being triggered. I want the onclick action to be triggered regardless if the textarea is focused...

Comment: Then use  $("#submit").click(); also inside the $("#post").focusout()